# open a modal window in jsp

Tags: javascript, jquery, window, modal-window

I was able to find one solution regarding modal windows, here is the link: [Simple jQuery Modal Window Examples](http://www.queness.com/resources/html/modal/jquery-modal-window.html).  However, what I want specifically is:

- I want to open b.jsp as a Simple Window Modal, like the one given in that website link above.
- After clicking the submit button I want b.jsp to open in that manner.

I tried several solutions, but I can't get it to work the same way.

Here is my code below:

```
a.jsp

<form action="b.jsp">
<input type="submit" value"click here to open modal window"/>
</form>
```

Answer (score 3):

Using JQuery UI is very easy.

I do some changes:

Change type to button because you don´t nee sudmit form for load html.

```
<div id="resultreturn" style="display: none"></div>
<form >
<input type="button" value="click here to open modal window" id="loader"/>
</form>
```

Later I bind a event click an in this event:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#loader").click(function(){
                // Load the page into the div
        $("#resultreturn").load("b.html");
                // Show the modal dialog
        $("#resultreturn").dialog({ modal: true });
    });
});
```

I hope this help you